# Accessing Cloud Firestore throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, dart

I found some similar question as this but I still didn't manage to get the solution for my case.
I am trying to implement a notification in my app but it has the error the following error:
I/flutter (11956): NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter (11956): Receiver: null
I/flutter (11956): Tried calling:

Please help to point out where I did my mistake.

I declared this as my path:
static const String noticationsPath = 'AdminNotifications';

[image]

This is the part I'm having the error.

```
Stream<SellerNotification> getNotifications() {
String uid = mAuth.currentUser.uid;

DocumentReference documentReference =
    db.collection(Paths.noticationsPath).doc(uid);
return documentReference.snapshots().transform(
      StreamTransformer<DocumentSnapshot, SellerNotification>.fromHandlers(
        handleData:
            (DocumentSnapshot docSnap, EventSink<SellerNotification> sink) {
          SellerNotification userNotification =
              SellerNotification.fromFirestore(docSnap);
          sink.add(userNotification);
        },
        handleError: (error, stackTrace, sink) {
          print('ERROR: $error');
          print(stackTrace);
          sink.addError(error);
        },
      ),
    ); }
```

Here's my class:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SellerNotification {
  String uid;
  bool unread;
  List<Notification> notifications;

  SellerNotification({
    this.notifications,
    this.uid,
    this.unread,
  });

  factory SellerNotification.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return SellerNotification(
      notifications: List<Notification>.from(
        documentSnapshot.data()['notifications'].map(
          (notif) {
            return Notification.fromMap(notif);
          },
        ),
      ),
      uid: documentSnapshot.data()['uid'],
      unread: documentSnapshot.data()['unread'],
    );
  }
}

class Notification {
  String notificationBody;
  String notificationId;
  String notificationTitle;
  String notificationType;
  String orderId;
  Timestamp timestamp;

  Notification({
    this.notificationBody,
    this.notificationId,
    this.notificationTitle,
    this.notificationType,
    this.orderId,
    this.timestamp,
  });

  factory Notification.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    return Notification(
      notificationBody: map['notificationBody'],
      notificationId: map['notificationId'],
      notificationTitle: map['notificationTitle'],
      notificationType: map['notificationType'],
      orderId: map['orderId'],
      timestamp: map['timestamp'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document ID should be the same as my uid that is why I cannot read my data.